# Is there already a comparison-interface in the framework 

Tags: c#, .net

which is equivalent to

```
interface ISomeKindOfCompare<T>
{
    bool Matches(T item);
}
```

I know IComparer and IEqualityComparer and so on, but that's not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) looks the same as your `ISomeKindOfCompare<T>`. That is, it lets you ask "is this object equal to some `T`?".

Answer (score 1):

[IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx)? [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx)?

Comment: Is there nothing with a bool as return-type? It's not that important but I dislike the int return type for it solves my problem not as pure as possible.